# ASP.NET WebAPI OData server side paging

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5, paging, odata

I've got an ASP.NET WebAPI OData service. One of the EntitySetController<,>.Get() methods returns an entity framework query. Since the entity framework query returns a lot of rows, I want to use server-side paging to keep the memory footprint reasonable. Also, $skiptoken is much faster than $skip in this case.

The [Queryable(PageSize = n)] attribute does not seem to accomplish exactly what I need for two reasons:

- They actual SQL query isn't paged. It's like it's doing .AsEnumerable().Take(n)
- The "next link" uses $skip instead of $skiptoken

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It seems WCF Data Services works the desired way be default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a work item for this:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/500

you can vote for. In the mean time, there's nothing stopping you from not using PageSize, and implementing paging yourself. `ODataQueryOptions` does expose the $skiptoken raw value for you to parse, and you can return a `PageResult<T>` to represent a page of your results with a next page link based on $skiptoken.